# How to replace href attribute value within JSX in tsx file?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, setattribute, tsx, queryselector

The default value of href of  tag is "https://default.xlsx", but I want to change the attribute value of href according to the ternary operator like that, but it doesn't work. What should I do?
Links in href are arbitrary(https://default.xlsx, https://change.xlsx). Since we are using JSX within the tsx file, we handled it between curly braces when using expressions.

No change from default "https://default.xlsx".

Seeing that all ternary operators with the same conditional statement ( selectedTab === TabLabel[Object.keys(TabType)[0]] ) in the same file work, the way to do it via .setAttribute() seems to be wrong.

```
<section>

<a href="https://default.xlsx" className="form-download-btn" download>
       Download Excel File
</a>

{selectedTab === TabLabel[Object.keys(TabType)[0]] 
? document.querySelector('a').setAttribute('href','https://default.xlsx')
: document.querySelector('a').setAttribute('href','https://change.xlsx')}

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use native DOM methods in React, except when selecting the root element, and when there's no other option. In this situation, change the `<a>`'s JSX markup to alternate between the hrefs.

```
<section>
<a
  href={
    selectedTab === TabLabel[Object.keys(TabType)[0]]
    ? 'https://default.xlsx'
    : 'https://change.xlsx'
  }
  className="form-download-btn"
  download
>
       Download Excel File
</a>
</section>
```